# Swift 3 replacingOccurrences exact

Tags: swift, regex, string

I'm having trouble with my replacingOccurrences function. I have a string like so:

```
let x = "john, johnny, johnney"
```

What I need to do is remove only "john"

So I have this code:

```
y = "john"
x = x.replacingOccurrences(of: y, with: " ", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
```

The problem I get is that this removes All instances of john... Also I thought about setting the range, however, that wont really solve my problem because the names could be in a different order.

Is there a CompareOptions func that I'm overlooking for "exact" or do I need to create a regular expression?

Sincerely,

Denis Angell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a regular expression to match the exact word, you just need to put the desired word between `\b`. Try like this:

```
let x = "johnny, john, johnney"
let y = "john"
let z = x.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b\(y)\\b", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)  // "johnny,  , johnney"
```

---

```
let x =  "johnny &john johnney"
let y = "&john"
let z = x.replacingOccurrences(of: y + "\\b", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: How would I do this if x = "johnny john johney"?

Comment: Sorry if x = "johnny &john johnney" and y = "&john"

Comment: I have a non letter before every word. So some words have one and some dont. Also, x could potentially be "&johnny &john johnney. So is there a way to include a non letter in my regrex string

Comment: Yeah I guess I will cuz it does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is probably your best option because there is no general rule for "exact" that would work in all languages.   In english, and most romance languages, you would define "exact" as having no alphabetical characters before or after the word to replace.

A regular expression could express that relatively simply for the english language as there are no complex letter combinations and a-z is pretty much all of it.  In other languages, you would have to worry about diacritical marks (french, other latin languages),  in Arabic you'd need to take into account the combined letter A (Aleph) at the beginning of some words, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!! I used regular expression in python but wasnt aware it was available in swift.